# How to solve APNS problems?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app. I integrated the apple push notification service. Its working yesterday but now its not working anymore. there is an error says that failed connection.

Comment: have you check with certificate?

Comment: Yes I have already checked all the certificates.